Unable to Authenticate with NTLM from Linux with .NET 8
I have a ASP.NET Core 8 Application which is being dockerized and deployed in Openshift.
The problem is that I cant authenticate to an endpoint using NTLM.
From my windows machine i can use it just fine, as expected, considering its both windows.
This is the output of the logged request inside the pod:
Request:
Method: GET
Target: 
Request Headers:
Response:
Status Code: ServiceUnavailable
Response Headers:
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-XSS-Protection: 1
Connection: close
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 768
I can call the endpoint manually by using curl with the --ntlm flag inside of the pods terminal. So connectivity should'nt be the problem.
I've tried using the standard aspnet:8.0 base image and also an alpine:latest
I've tried installing the gss-ntlmssp onto the aspnet base image, cant get it to install tho:
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease' is not signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bookworm/InRelease  403  Forbidden 

I've tried installing the krb5-libs when using the alpine base image (gss-ntlmssp isnt available on alpine).
And i've also tried setting the UseManagedNtlm
``<ItemGroup>
  <RuntimeHostConfiguration Include="System.Net.Security.UseManagedNtlm" Value="true"/>
</ItemGroup>` `

both in the .csproj and in the Program.cs with:
AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Security.UseManagedNtlm", true);
as suggested by the various GitHub threads regarding this topic.
This is my HttpClient:
...
private static HttpClient s_client;

    private static void CreateHttpClientWithNtlmAuth(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var aDUser = configuration["SRV_USER"];
        var aDPassword = configuration["SRV_PASSWORD"];

        HttpClientHandler hand = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(aDUser, aDPassword, "<domain>"),
            PreAuthenticate = true,

        };

        s_client = new HttpClient(new LoggingHandler(hand));
    }

...

I think that i've tried every possbile permutation of requested fixes but cant seem to get it to work. So there must be something I am missing. Appreciate any help.

Windows authentication actually uses Kerberos since the 2000s. For that to work, the machine has to join the same domain as the server, something done using command-line tools. In integrated authentication the client sends a token that represents the current account to the server. The server validates with the domain controller (or another Kerberos controller) that the token is valid and what user it represents. You can't do any of that in code

Configuring your machine is explained in the Linux and macOS environment configuration section of Configure Windows Authentication in ASP.NET Core and even more detailed in Connect Azure Data Studio to SQL Server using Kerberos. Essentially, you're logging into the domain controller with an account, and storing the ticket

@PanagiotisKanavos If that would be the case, shouldnt I also not be able to reach the endpoint using curl from the pods terminal?

I can't guess what your topology is or how it's configured. curl isn't the OS or the browser, or a typical client. It works because it's built with the proper protocols and will negotiate with the server to find the correct one. The -u parameter documentation explains just how much curl does to connect if the binary supports this. In fact, it even talks about the Kerberos ticket. Using a username and password doesn't mean they're sent to the server. It's easier to impersonate the user locally and make the call as that user.

To test this, use WSL on Windows to test various approaches. This will eliminate networking issues like eg blocked ports. Don't depend on --ntlm. It's an old protocol and may not even be enabled. Disabling it is a common hardening step since the ability to disable was introduced in 2010

In any case, I pointed to the actual docs that explain how to configure Windows Authentication on Linux. kinit adds your machine to the domain, after which Linux itself can use Kerberos. I've used those steps to connect to SQL Server on Windows from MacOS, so I know they work. You should first try the guide to get a simple web app to work before experimenting, just to see how a working implementation looks

You can try download gss-ntlmssp in your docker file.
Example: RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gss-ntlmssp
